# Angular 4 sends another request header in production environment

Tags: angular, request

I struggle fairly odd situation while Angular (4.0.0) is sending request with content-type header application/json in development environment and another one while making the same request in production environment. In production (ACC) it sends text/html. Thus I'm receiving strange response with html inside. Has anyone encountered similar situation? Firstly I didn't set content-type header explicitly, but I've changed it in my code, but any progress.

I'm using @angular/http module for preparing requests in this project.

Any help appreciated

Comment: maybe a OPTION reeust ? ..could it be?

Comment: What is the actual body of the request being sent? Angular will automatically detect content type based on the content of the body you are sending

Comment: I didn't get it : do you have an issue on how to make different headers according to the environment, or is the issue the response from your server ?

Comment: The request does not have any body - it is GET method. Is has only query params. The problem is that I'm getting unexpected response (another one in dev and prod environment). I observed that requests in these two env differ in request content-type.